# Optimization problem where the objective function not differentiable

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

$$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\max_{i=1 \dots m}\{\langle\nabla f_i({\overline{x}}),x-\overline{x}\rangle\}+\sigma\|x-\overline{x}\|^2 \tag 1,$$

where $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $F(x)=(f_{1}(x), \dots,f_{m}(x))$. I tried to solve this problem, but could not finish it. Could someone please help me?

---

This is part of my solution:

Solve problem (1) is equivalent to solve
\begin{align}
   \min\limits_{x,z}&\quad z&\hspace{4cm} (2)& \\
   \text{s.t}& \quad \langle \nabla f_i({\overline{x}}),x-\overline{x}\rangle+\sigma\|x-\overline{x}\|^2 \leq z&& 
\end{align}
the Langragian dual problem associated with $(2)$ is:

$$\max_{\mu\geq 0}q(\mu)\tag 3,$$ with $$q(\mu)=\inf L(x,z,\mu)$$
and $$L(x,z,\mu)= z+\sum_{i=1}^m\mu_i(\langle \nabla f_i({\overline{x}}),x-\overline{x}\rangle+\sigma\|x-\overline{x}\|^2-z)$$.
the problem (3) is equivalent to solve
$$\max_{\mu\geq 0} \min_{x,z}\left(1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \mu_i\right)z + \sum \limits_{i=1}^m \mu_i(\langle\nabla f_i(\overline{x}),x-\overline{x}\rangle + \sigma\|x-\overline{x}\|^2), $$
$$(x^\ast,z^\ast)=\operatorname*{arg min}_{x,z} \left(1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \mu_i\right)z+\sum_{i=1}^m \mu_i(\langle \nabla f_i(\overline{x}),x-\overline{x}\rangle + \sigma\|x-\overline{x}\|^2),$$
$$\nabla_{x,z} L(x^\ast,z^\ast,\mu^\ast)=0$$
this is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^m\mu_i^\ast\nabla f_i(\overline{x}) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^m 2\mu_i^\ast \sigma(x^\ast-\overline{x})  \\
    1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\mu_i^\ast \\
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
    0
    \end{pmatrix}$$
This problem has a solution when:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}\mu_{1}=1$$
and
$$x^{\ast}=-\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\mu_i\nabla f_i(\overline{x})}{2\sigma\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\mu_i}+\overline{x}$$
$$x^{\ast}=-\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\mu_i\nabla f_i(\overline{x})}{2\sigma} + \overline{x}.$$
I do not know what else to do, what would be the solution to my original problem? and what would be the value of $z^{\ast}$?

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle \nabla f_i(\overline{x}),x-\overline{x}\rangle,$ not $< \nabla f_i({\overline{x}}),x-\overline{x}>.$ I changed that and some other things.

Comment: This is a standard formulation of a search direction problem (similar to a trust region approach). It might be easier to solve using von Neumann's minimax theorem (or some variant).

Answer (score 2):

Let $C = \operatorname{co} \{ \nabla f_k( \bar{x} ) \}$ and observe that $C$ is
a compact convex set. Note that the problem
is equivalent to 
$\min_h \max_{\xi \in C} \langle \xi, h \rangle + \sigma \|h\|^2$.

A little work shows that a solution must lie in a compact convex set (because of the $\|h\|^2$ term)
and the map $(h,\xi) \to \langle \xi, h \rangle + \sigma \|h\|^2$ is convex
in $h$ and concave (in fact, linear) in $\xi$.

We can apply von Neumann's minimax theorem to exchange the $\min, \max$ to get
$\max_{\xi \in C} \min_h  \langle \xi, h \rangle + \sigma \|h\|^2$.

We see that the inner problem has a unique solution $\xi = -2 \sigma h$, and
so the problem reduces to
$\max_{\xi \in C} -{1 \over 4 \sigma} \|\xi \|^2 = - {1 \over 4 \sigma} \min_{\xi \in C}  \|\xi \|^2$.

In particular, the solution is given by the unique point of minimal norm
in $C$.

Adjusting $\sigma$ has an effect similar to a step size, except that increasing
$\sigma$ has a similar effect to reducing the stepsize.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Delta_m$ be the $m$-simplex and note that the maximum of a linear function on $\Delta_m$ is attained on a vertex (this is elementary, and dates back to Nash). Thus
$$\max_{i} \langle \nabla f_i(\bar{x}), x-\bar{x}\rangle = \max_{z \in \Delta_m}\langle \nabla F(\bar{x})^T(x-\bar{x}),z\rangle = \max_{z \in \Delta_m}\langle x-\bar{x},\nabla F(\bar{x})z\rangle.
$$
Thus by [Sion's minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem), one has

$$
\begin{split}
\min_{x \in \mathbb R^n}\max_{i} \langle \nabla f_i(\bar{x}), x-\bar{x}\rangle + \frac{\sigma}{2}\|x-\bar{x}\|_2^2
&= \min_{x \in \mathbb R^n}\max_{z \in \Delta_m}\langle x-\bar{x},\nabla F(\bar{x})z\rangle\\
&= \max_{z \in \Delta_m}\min_{x \in \mathbb R^n}\langle x-\bar{x},\nabla F(\bar{x})z\rangle + \frac{\sigma}{2}\|x-\bar{x}\|_2^2\\
&= \max_{z \in \Delta_m} \langle -\frac{1}{\sigma}\nabla F(\bar{x})z,\nabla F(\bar{x})z\rangle + \frac{\sigma}{2}\|\frac{1}{\sigma}\nabla F(\bar{x})\|_2^2\\
&= \max_{z \in \Delta_m} -\frac{1}{2\sigma}\|\nabla F(\bar{x})z\|_2^2 = -\frac{1}{2\sigma}\min_{u \in C}\|u\|_2^2,
\end{split}
$$

where $C := \{z_i\nabla f_i(\bar{x}) | z \in \Delta_m\} =: \operatorname{co}(\nabla F(\bar{x})$.